# Using Ultrasonic sensor HC-SR04 and Gps (neogps 6m) together on arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to read data from both the sensor and the gps (one by one is ok). The sensors work well individually but the Ultrasonic sensor does not give any output. I am new to arduino so i just mixed the codes from the two examples using NewPing Library and TinyGPS libraries. Here is the code. Please suggest what additions need to be made to the code to make both devices work together.

```
/*********************
 *10 to GPS Module TX*
 *09 to GPS Module RX*
 *********************/
//  1.TESTED USING LED
// 2. added ultrasound libraries 
 #include <NewPing.h>

#define TRIGGER_PIN  5 // Arduino pin tied to trigger pin on the ultrasonic sensor.
#define ECHO_PIN     4 // Arduino pin tied to echo pin on the ultrasonic sensor.
#define MAX_DISTANCE 400 // Maximum distance we want to ping for (in centimeters). Maximum sensor distance is rated at 400-500cm.

NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE); // NewPing setup of pins and maximum distance.

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>



SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11);

TinyGPS gps;

float gpsdump(TinyGPS &gps);


void setup()  
{
  // Oploen serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);




}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  bool newdata = false;
  unsigned long start = millis();
  // Every 5 seconds we print an update
  while (millis() - start < 5000) 
  {
    if (mySerial.available()) 

    {
      char c = mySerial.read();
      //Serial.print(c);  // uncomment to see raw GPS data
      if (gps.encode(c)) 
      {
        newdata = true;
        break;  // uncomment to print new data immediately!
      }
    }
  }

  if (newdata) 
  {
    Serial.println("Acquired Data");
    Serial.println("-------------");
    gpsdump(gps);

    Serial.println("-------------");
    Serial.println();
  }

}


float gpsdump(TinyGPS &gps)
{

  // On Arduino, GPS characters may be lost during lengthy Serial.print()
  // On Teensy, Serial prints to USB, which has large output buffering and
  //   runs very fast, so it's not necessary to worry about missing 4800
  //   baud GPS characters.


  Serial.println("speed");
   Serial.println(gps.f_speed_kmph()) ;
   Serial.print(sonar.ping_cm());
  ;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problems:

- You cannot wait 5 seconds without processing the characters.  The Arduino receive buffer only has room for 64 characters.  The GPS device could have sent 5000 characters during that time, so most of them will get dropped.  This prevents the GPS library from *ever* parsing a complete sentence.
- A ping will interfere with software serial ports.  You will have to wait for the [GPS quiet time](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/extras/doc/Troubleshooting.md#quiet-time-interval) to do the ping.  Otherwise, the ping process will cause characters to be lost.

Other problems:

- You are printing the speed value even though it may not be valid.  If you are not moving, or you do not have good satellite reception, the GPS device may not provide a speed.
- The Arduino `millis()` clock will not be synchronized with the GPS clock.  You could use the GPS updates as an *exact* 1-second clock.  Simply count 5 fixes as they arrive, and this will mean that 5 seconds have elapsed.
- You should use a different serial port and/or library. 
  [This answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/34126#34130) describes the various choices: `HardwareSerial` (i.e. `Serial` on pins 0 & 1), `AltSoftSerial` (8 & 9 on an UNO) or `NeoSWSerial` (any two pins).

Here is a [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS) version of your sketch that addresses these issues:

```
/*********************
 *10 to GPS Module TX*
 *09 to GPS Module RX*
 *********************/
//  1.TESTED USING LED
// 2. added ultrasound libraries 
 #include <NewPing.h>

#define TRIGGER_PIN  5 // Arduino pin tied to trigger pin on the ultrasonic sensor.
#define ECHO_PIN     4 // Arduino pin tied to echo pin on the ultrasonic sensor.
#define MAX_DISTANCE 400 // Maximum distance we want to ping for (in centimeters). Maximum sensor distance is rated at 400-500cm.

NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE); // NewPing setup of pins and maximum distance.

#include <NeoSWSerial.h>
#include <NMEAGPS.h>


NeoSWSerial gpsPort(10, 11);

NMEAGPS gps;          // the parser
gps_fix fix;          // all the parsed values from GPS
uint8_t fixCount = 0; // a one-second "clock"

float gpsdump();


void setup()  
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  gpsPort.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);

}



void loop() // run over and over
{
  // Check for available GPS characters and parse them
  if (gps.available( gpsPort ))
  {
    //  Once per second, a complete fix structure is ready.
    fix = gps.read();
    fixCount++;

    //  The GPS device is going to be quiet for a while,
    //     *now* is a good time to do a ping.
    Serial.print( "ping " );
    Serial.println( sonar.ping_cm() );

    // Every 5 seconds we print an update
    if (fixCount >= 5)
    {
      fixCount = 0; // reset counter

      Serial.println("Acquired Data");
      Serial.println("-------------");
      gpsdump();
      Serial.println("-------------");
      Serial.println();
    }
  }
}


float gpsdump()
{
  // On Arduino, GPS characters may be lost during lengthy Serial.print()
  // On Teensy, Serial prints to USB, which has large output buffering and
  //   runs very fast, so it's not necessary to worry about missing 4800
  //   baud GPS characters.

  Serial.println("speed ");
  if (fix.valid.speed)
    Serial.println( fix.speed_kph() );

}
```

If you want to try it, NeoGPS, AltSoftSerial and NeoSWSerial are available from the IDE Library Manager, under the menu **Sketch -> Include Library -> Manage Libraries**.  NeoGPS is smaller, faster, more reliable and more accurate than all other libraries.

Even if you don't use it, there are many suggestions on the Installation and Troubleshooting pages.

Comment: Thank you so much :) helped a lot!

Comment: @GurjeetSinghBali, Glad to help!  If this solved your problem, click that green checkmark on my answer to accept it.  Otherwise, it lingers as an unanswered question for days, months, years...  haunting me forever.  :)